# Is there a way to deprecate only the setter of a variable?

Tags: swift, model, deprecated

I currently have a variable in a class `open var deviceIdentifier: String?` and would like to deprecate the setter only turning it into `open private(set) var deviceIdentifier: String?`

Is there any way to do that? I tried to put both lines in but that is obviously a conflict Xcode doesn't like.

```
@available(*, deprecated)
open var deviceIdentifier: String?

open private(set) var deviceIdentifier: String?
```

The compiler is happy if I change it to a computed variable but I'd like to avoid that. Is this the only way, and will this work as expected?

```
private var _deviceIdentifier: String?
open var deviceIdentifier: String? {
    get {
        return _deviceIdentifier
    }
    @available(*, deprecated)
    set(newValue){

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I would also like to know if there is a solution for this I had a quick look awhile back and couldn't find anything but it was low priority so I didn't spend much time on it.

Comment: If [set-only computed properties](https://forums.swift.org/t/set-only-computed-properties/14550/9) were made possible, it would could conceivably be made possible that the `get` and `set` declarations can be split, allowing to deprecate just one of them.

Comment: I think your solution, using a computed property. Is best for now. Once I want remove the setter then you can go with making the setter private.

Comment: @leogdion I just tested the computed property and adding the `@available` annotation does provide a compiler warning in Xcode 10 though not in Xcode 9. Moving forward with that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the only way to do this right now is with a computed variable, but it does work as expected.

```
//TODO: put back to non-computed variable when making set private
private var _deviceIdentifier: String?    
open var deviceIdentifier: String? {
    get {
        return _deviceIdentifier
    }
    @available(*, deprecated)
    set(newValue) {
        _deviceIdentifier = newValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I think it is enough to place `private(set) var deviceIdentifier: String?`, when someone tries to set the value of this variable the compiler will report that it is not possible.

[image: > Cannot assign to property: 'deviceIdentifier' setter is inaccessible]

Comment: There is a slight difference between deprecated and not allowed.